# Failed to Load JSON file in Azure Website

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, azure

My website has a Javacript which is loading a JSON file from a directory, its working fine on local server but when i publish it on Azure, it doesn't show anything. I high doubt its path format problem, please help. Code is below

`map.data.loadGeoJson('../Maps/ws.json');`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137750/azure-web-app-does-not-load-json-file helpful? More references: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/africaapps/how-to-serve-static-json-files-from-a-windows-azure-website

Comment: Thanks man. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue, FTP into your website and upload the following Web.config file which will set the correct MIME types. If you already have a Web.config file in place, just add the below to the appropriate section.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".json"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
     </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```